# How to create a list of links

Tags: scala, playframework

I'd like to have a home page that contains a list of links to other parts of my app. So, instead of having harcoded hrefs like         `<a href="@controllers.routes.SomeModel.show(someModel.ean)">` I figured I'd create a Link object like that contains a list of links that I can pass to that page through the controller and then render each link. But I'm not clear on how to actually reference the link.

```
 case class Link(name: String, route: String)

    object Link {
      val links = Set(Link("SomeModels", controllers.SomeModels.list.toString()),
        Link("Products", controllers.Products.list.toString()))

      def allLinks = links.toList
    }
```

And I wanted to use this like this:

```
@(links: List[Link])(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
@main("welcome to my awesome play app") {
<dl class="models">
    @for(link <- links) {
    <dt>
        <a href=@link.route>
            @link.name
        </a>
    </dt>
    }
</dl>
}
```

But it doesn't work obviously because those actually link to `http://localhost:9000/Action(parser=BodyParser(anyContent))` so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put ".routes" between "controllers" and you Controller name and use the method "url":

```
case class Link(name: String, route: String)

object Link {
  val links = List(Link("SomeModels", controllers.routes.SomeModels.list.url),
    Link("Products", controllers.routes.Products.list.url))

  def allLinks = links.toList
}
```

I made a gist with working code for play 2.0.4: https://gist.github.com/4275931